# How to get filename using os.path.basename without the '> extension

Tags: python, filepath

I'm trying to get a string that contains only the filename. I know you can use `os.path.basename` to get the just the filename without the pathway. However, this still keeps the '> portion of the name. I want to only get the filename, without anything else.

I.E.

```
<_io.BufferedReader name='C:/Users/Sams PC/Desktop/file.txt'>
#printout using os.path.basename
file.txt'>
##Desired
file.txt
```

For some context of what I'm using to get this, this is my script (its using `tkinter`):

```
def browse():
    result=tk.filedialog.askopenfile(parent=root,mode='rb',title='Choose a file')
    return result
print(browse())
print(os.path.basename(str(browse())))
```

Comment: If you want a filename, rather than an actual opened file object, you should be using `askopenfilename()` instead of `askopenfile()`.

Comment: I agree with @jasonharper , and BufferedReader object also has an attribute `name`. If you need to read this file later, you could get name by ` reader = browse(); os.path.basename(reader.name)`

Comment: You are using str() on an object, not the file name.  The fact that the name appears in the object description is largely luck.  Change `str(browse())` to `browse().name` is one approach.   The other comments here have even better advice.

Comment: If I try to print(browse()) using askopenfilename(), I get an error: _tkinter.TclError: bad option "-mode": must be -defaultextension, -filetypes, -initialdir, -initialfile, -multiple, -parent, -title, or -typevariable

Comment: @RufusVS browse().name prints out the entire path (I only want the filename)

Comment: use os.path.basename() function on it, as had before.

Comment: @RufusVS this works but I don't understand why? How does the .name get rid of '>?

Comment: Because the `os.path.basename()` doesn't check if you gave it a valid path name in the first place.  That string you gave it that had `'>` in it was _**not**_ a valid path name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `filedialog.askopenfilename` instead of `filedialog.askopenfile` to obtain the filename without side effects (like opening a file). This returns the full path; you can extract the filename from the fullpath using `os.path.basename`

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def browse():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    fullpath = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, title='Choose a file')
    filename = os.path.basename(fullpath)
    root.destroy()

    return filename

print(browse())
```

Comment: As I stated to someone who had posted in comments, this is what I get: when I use askopenfilename: _tkinter.TclError: bad option "-mode": must be -defaultextension, -filetypes, -initialdir, -initialfile, -multiple, -parent, -title, or -typevariable –

Comment: indeed, `askopenfilename` does not have a `mode` option. If you read the code I wrote carefully, you will see there is no `mode` parameter passed in the signature! You are still confusing `askopenfile` which returns an opened file, with `askopenfilename` which returns a fullpath. You were "trying to get a string that contains only the filename", this is what my code does!